# Git Merge Issue- Everything up-to-date

Tags: git, github, merge

I, being not so good in Git, played around with it and couldn't push my changes onto the GIT.

Here's the issue.

I've 2 branches. Master and temp. I checked out on branch from master, and now I'm currently on temp.

I want to merge the changes from temp into master. Following are the steps I followed.

```
#Pushing changes from temp to remote.

git push origin temp.
```

Now, I checked out to master and removed the merge conflicts.

```
git checkout master
git merge master temp
```

Now, I'm trying to push changes to master, it says `everything is upto date`. Even if I make any changes in any file from `master` branch and try to push it, it says `everything is upto date`. The changes have been merged locally, but not on remote.

I'm tired of this issue. Have read a multiple SO questions over this. But cant make it work.

What exactly is wrong?

PS: I made some mistakes by going back to a previous commit and my head got detached. (Read this later that we should go back to a previous commit.) This might be the reason that I'm getting this error.

Comment: it makes me problem also.... when i pushed my code it said up to date but actually on git not update.......... then i actually do the right click on the project name above the side tab name project .. Git>Commit Directory and push and commit

Comment: Give more information : "git status"  ;  when you do the "git checkout master"  do you have any message  ? did you do a "git commit"  temp ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to push temp to make a merge. Only to save it on the rmeote side. A merge remains a local operation.

Second, [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) will merge branch(es) into the current branch.

So to merge `temp` into `master`, you need to checkout `master`, and merge `temp`:

```
git checkout master
git merge temp
```